# Why does an object in simple harmonic motion have kinetic energy at its equilibrium point?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, harmonic-oscillator, spring

While an object is undergoing simple harmonic motion, its kinetic energy tends to vary with its position.  This kinetic energy is highest when it's at the point where the forces on it are at equilibrium, exactly canceling each other out.

**Question:**  Why is kinetic energy greatest at the equilibrium point in simple harmonic oscillation?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You seem to be attempting to answer it yourself, and it's unclear what you don't know.

Comment: Welcome to SE.Physics!  I tried to edit your post for clarify; please feel free to revert the edit if it's in error, or further [edit] your post if you'd like to change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a simple harmonic oscillator, energy is *conserved*;  in other words, the sum of the kinetic and potential energy is always the same.  But the potential energy is at a minimum when the object is at its equilibrium position;  specifically, the potential energy is zero.  This means that all of the object's energy must be kinetic when it's at the equilibrium point.

At any other point, the potential energy is positive.  This means that the object's kinetic energy is less than the total energy.  Thus, the kinetic energy has its maximum value at equilibrium, where it is equal to the object's total energy.

This is a general principle, by the way:  if energy is conserved, then a higher potential energy implies a lower kinetic energy and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

Conservation of energy. In harmonic motion the energy is:
$$E=K+U$$
K is the kinetic energy: $K=\frac 1 2 m v^2$
U is the potential energy: $U=\frac 1 2 kx^2$

Since $E$ is constant by conservation of energy, and both $K$ and $U$ are non negative, you have that $K=E-U$ is maximum when $U=0$, which happens at $x=0$, i.e. equilibrium position.